# C++ Include From Internet

Tags: c++, header, cross-compiling

I want include a header from internet. For example: file add.h and add.cpp have been post to github.com

file add.h is  int add(int a,int b);

file add.cpp is int add(int a,int b){return a+b;}

in my main.cpp I want the code like this

```
#include "github.com/xxx/add.h"
int main(){
int a = add(1,1);
}
```

When compile begin,compiler can auto download add.cpp from github.com

Can this happen?

Answer (score 4):

No it's not going to happen (assuming you're not using some sort of fetching machinery). Only local files are included by the preprocessor with an `#include` directive.

**C++ doesn't work like Go or Javascript**

Files hosted on github are meant to be checked out using [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) and then used.

I recommend reading a C++ and a Git book before continuing (or your compiler/build system manual to add extra fetching steps)

Comment: Unless of course if someone builds a virtual drive that goes to Github and grabs the stuff. I'll stop there before I give anyone any crazy ideas.

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not support that feature natively. You would have to build it yourself.

You could add an extra step to your build system that

1. parses your source code for includes like the one in your example above
2. downloads the include files (and also required `*.cpp` *somehow*)
3. generates an updated version of your source code that references the downloaded files.
4. then continues the build as usual

This is **a lot of work**.

Better look into something like [`ExternalProjects`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) of CMake. This feature can download, build, and install dependencies so your project can use it. Of course, alternative technologies exist (@ commentators please add your favorites).

**UPDATE:** (thanks @Angew)

> Technically, C++ does not specify how the argument of a #include directive is processed. It's all the known compilers which "don't support this feature natively," not C++ itself. A compiler which supported this could be fully standard-compliant.

Comment: Technically, C++ does not specify how the argument of a `#include` directive is processed. It's *all the known compilers* which "don't support this feature natively," not C++ itself. A compiler which supported this could be fully standard-compliant.